# HTML input field with automatically retrieving the granularity from minutes, hours and days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input-field

I need to have an input field to set the duration.

The user will have the possibility to set this duration in `minutes`, `hours` or `days`

For example, I would like to give the possibility to have inputs like:

```
1m
8.5 h
3d
```

etc

I will convert the value to minutes before to send the value to the backend.

Do you know some inputs plugins to have this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) you can allow inputs as follows:

```js
const threeMinuts = '3m';       // 3 minutes
const eightHours  = '8.5 h';    // 8.5 hours
const threeDays   = '3 days';      // 3 days
```

You then have to separate the number value from the unit of measurement:

```js
const numberValue = Number(input.match(/(\d|\.|,)+/)[0]);
const unit = input.match(/[a-z]+/)[0];
```

after which you can pass the duration to moment as follows:

```js
const duration = moment.duration(numberValue, unit);
```

e.g.:

```js
const duration = moment.duration(8.5, 'h');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Assign each `<input>` `type="number"` and `min="0"`.
2. Then `max="23"` for hours and `max="59"` for minutes.
3. Add a hidden input with a `name` attribute.
4. If you haven't already, wrap everything in a `<form>` and register it to the `"input"` event.
5. Create an event handler to extract and calculate the values of all of the inputs and then assign the total to the hidden input.
6. When the `<form>` is submitted, the hidden input value will be sent since it has a `name` attribute.

BTW it isn't really good UX to have a user type in so many values in one input. You should provide the user clearly defined fields that require the user to enter data without extra complications.

---

#### Demo

```js
document.forms.duration.oninput = toMinutes;

function toMinutes(e) {
  const dur = this.elements;
  let time;
  if (e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    let d = Number(dur.days.value) * 1440;
    let h = Number(dur.hours.value) * 60;
    let m = Number(dur.minutes.value);
    time = d + h + m;
    dur.time.value = time;
  }
  console.log(dur.time.value);
}
```

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 400 3vw/1.45 Consolas
}

fieldset {
  width: max-content;
}

label,
input {
  width: 6.5ch;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}

input {
  height: 3vw;
  line-height: 1;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: right
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<form id='duration'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Duration</legend>
    <label for='days'>Days: </label>
    <input id='days' type='number' min='0' value='0'><br>
    <label for='hours'>Hours: </label>
    <input id='hours' type='number' min='0' max='23' value='0'><br>
    <label for='minutes'>Minutes: </label>
    <input id='minutes' type='number' min='0' max='59' value='0'><br>
  </fieldset>
  <input id='time' name='time' type='hidden'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I prefer pure JS and no libs (with a heavy overhead) here a simple JS for this task adapt (esp the regex eg for hours (/([0-9]0-9?)[ ]?h/) for digits) as you like:

```
function toSeconds(dd,hh,mm) {
 var d = parseInt(dd);
  var h = parseInt(hh);
  var m = parseInt(mm);
  if (isNaN(d)) d = 0;
  if (isNaN(h)) h = 0;
  if (isNaN(m)) m = 0;

 var t = d * 24 * 60 * 60 +
      h * 60 * 60 +
      m * 60;
  return t;
}

/* Expects 1d 11h 11m, or 1d 11h, or 11h 11m, 
or 11h, or 11m, or 1d returns number of seconds */
function parseInput(sInput) {
  if (sInput== null || sInput=== '') return 0;
  var mrx = new RegExp(/([0-9][0-9]?)[ ]?m/);
  var hrx = new RegExp(/([0-9][0-9]?)[ ]?h/);
  var drx = new RegExp(/([0-9])[ ]?d/);
  var days = 0;
  var hours = 0;
  var minutes = 0;
  if (mrx.test(sInput)) {
    minutes = mrx.exec(sInput)[1];
  }
  if (hrx.test(sInput)) {
    hours = hrx.exec(sInput)[1];
  }
  if (drx.test(sInput)) {
    days = drx.exec(sInput)[1];
  }

  return toSeconds(days, hours, minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you create input

```
<input id="time" type="time">
```

Finally, you add value into input using javascript

```
document.getElementById("time").value = new Date().toTimeString().slice(0,8);
```